# Minimizing a line integral in 2 dimensions : $\inf \int_{(a,b)}^{(c,d)} f(r(t)) |r'(t)| dt$

Tags: polynomials, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum, line-integrals, scalar-fields

Let $x,y,z$ be real.

Consider a scalar field

$$z = f(x,y)$$

More specific; $f(x,y)$ is a (given) real polynomial in $x,y$ of degree at most $5$ such that

For all $x,y$

$$f(x,y)> 0$$

For a given pair of points $(a,b),(c,d)$ ($a,c$ are the x-part and $b,d$ are the y-part) consider the line integral

$$I(f(x,y)) = \int_C f(r) ds = \int_{(a,b)}^{(c,d)} f(r(t)) |r'(t)| dt = \int_{(a,b)}^{(c,d)} f(r_1(t),r_2(t)) |r'(t)| dt$$

Where the line integral is along a piecewise smooth curve $C$ , $r$ is a bijective parametrization of the curve $C$ and the absolute value bars denote the standard (Euclidean) norm (length) of a vector.

(The line integral over the scalar field $f$ can be thought of as the area under the curve $C$ along a surface $z = f(x,y)$, described by the field. Also $r_1,r_2$ are the $x$ and $y$ part of the parametrization by $r(t)$)

Now the question is how to minimize (global minimum) this value :

$$ A = \inf I(f(x,y))$$

How to find the value of $A$ and the Curve(s) $C$ that gives this value $A$ ?

I assume they have a closed form, or at least they are the solution of a differential equation.

Calculus of variations probably relates to this, but I know little about it.

A trivial case is if $f(x,y)$ is a constant.
Then the path is a straith line and $A$ is the length of that line.
(The shortest distance is "always" given by a straith line, what can be shown easily by the Euler-Lagrange equation)

The complication arises thus from the higher degrees.

***edit***

Solutions of degree $3$ could perhaps also be accepted.
I lowered my demands since it appears to be not so easy for degree $5$.
They will get upvoted probably, but ofcourse if a better answer or degree of $5$ gets solved that gets a higher chance.

Comment: square brackets for the points would be better I guess

Comment: It is clear this is not a conservative vector field, so the path matters

Comment: Yes, this is definitely calculus of variations. (If you refer to Euler-Lagrange, then you already know that.) There is no vector field to be conservative. Also, fix the endpoints of the $t$-interval, say $0$ and $1$, integrate $\int_0^1 \dots dt$, and the constraints are $r(0)=(a,b)$ and $r(1)=(c,d)$.

Comment: Here’s what I get from Euler-Lagrange. Either 
(1) $C$ is a level curve $f= c$ and on it $\|\nabla f\|=c\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is its curvature … or
(2) $\|r’\|=1$ and the normal component of $\nabla f$ has magnitude $f\kappa$ at each point.

Comment: I think one special case is: if $f$ is a piecewise constant function, with straight lines separating the domains, then the solution is a path of straight lines with the bend at each boundary line satisfying Snell's law.  (Related to Huygens' principle.)  I wonder if the general solution could be derived by some limiting process on that special case.

Comment: @DanielSchepler hmm I think that would lead to graph theory without a closed form solution.

Comment: @TedShifrin what kind of curvature ? What is meant by magnitude of normal component ?  A level curve is not possible if the end and start point are not at the same level. And I doubt it is universally true. As for case 2 : the norm being 1 , is that then the shortest length of the path ; a straith line ?

Comment: Curvature of a plane curve is the rate at which its (unit) tangent turns. No, every curve can be reparametrized so that it has speed $1$. Notice the very complex condition involving curvature there too. It involves the geometry of your path ($\kappa$) and both $f$ and $\nabla f$. I have no idea what some simple examples are.

Comment: @TedShifrin you say magnitude $f k$ but f is a function of $f(x,y)$ , so you mean $f(x,y)$ times $k$ or ?

Comment: Yes, everything is a function of where you are.$f(r(t))$, $\kappa(t)$, etc.

Comment: I worked out the Euler-Lagrange equations and interpreted them. Imdo not think this is a problem with a feasible solution. It might be interesting to work out the case of quadratic $f$.